# Hermitian & Skew Hermitian Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Why will a hermitian/skew-hermitian transformation always have an eigen-basis ?
i.e. why will there always be distinct $n$eigenvalues for a hermitian transformation where $n=Dim (V)$, where the hermitian/skewhermitian transformation is $T:V \rightarrow W$.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the spectral theorem for hermitian matrices. There are many different approaches that can be taken to prove it, all involving many lines and arguments.

One approach is to use Schur's Theorem, which guarantees that for a square matrix $A$ there are unitary matrix $U$ 
($U^*U=I$) and upper triangular $T$, such that

$T=U^*AU$.

In our case, $A$ is hermitian, hence $T$ is hermitian and therefore diagonal (since upper triangular and hermitian).
Therefore, $A$ is (unitarily) similar to a diagonal matrix. 
This tells us that $A$ must have a 'full' set of eigenvectors. Note: its eigenvalues are not necessarily distinct. For example: 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 &0& 0\\0 &1 &0\\0& 0 &0\end{bmatrix}$$